# Using .htaccess to clean GET URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Before anyone comments, I know there are a lot of posts created on this topic, but none of them seem to solve my problem, that is why I have started this thread.

So, I have a page in my website called `project.php` which is used in `GET` query like so: `project.php?id=12` I want to have a .htaccess file that converts the given URL into `localhost/MyWeb/project/id/12/`. I've literally followed every single post regarding that topic but none of them seem to work.

Also, along with that, I want all my `.php` and `.html` files to be shown just with their names, i.e `localhost/MyWeb/index.php/` becomes `localhost/MyWeb/index/` and `localhost/MyWeb/sub1/sub2.php` becomes `localhost/MyWeb/sub1/sub2/`.

**EDIT:**

The reason why I did not add my work in first place was because I didn't think it would be any helpful. But here it is:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ project.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ project.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Show your attempts/concrete research so far. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason why I did not add my work in first place was because I didn't think it would be any helpful. But I've updated my post.

Comment: @TayabSoomro - the reason posting your attempts is helpful to us is because it gives us the opportunity to show you where you may have gone wrong, instead of just providing the answers you seek. But that's just one reason... Now that you have posted the code, I can see were you went wrong. Will post an answer now

Comment: I understand that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are operating out of a sub-directory (`MyWeb`), which means you need to set a `RewriteBase`. Also, you need to ensure that your `.htaccess` file is placed inside that sub-directory, and not in the localhost document root.

So, below `RewriteEngine on`, insert the folloeing line:

```bash
RewriteBase /MyWeb/
```

Next, you stated that you want to convert `project.php?id={id}` to `project/id/{id}`, but your code omits the `/id/` segment. I also noticed that you have two rules, and that the second one contradicts your question, so I am only going to show you the change you need to make for the first rule, until such time as you clarify what the second rule is for.

To make the project URI work, change the very first rule to:

```bash
RewriteRule ^project/id/([0-9]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will match the URI you want, with an optional trailing slash. I've also added the `QSA` flag which appends any extra query string parameters to the rewitten URI, as well as the `L` flag which stops processing if the rule is matched.

Next, to omit the `.php` or `.html` from your URIs, change the last three lines to the following:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

When you make a request to `localhost/MyWeb/index`, Apache will check to see if `localhost/MyWeb/index.php` or `localhost/MyWeb/index.html` exist, and will then serve whichever one it finds first.

If you have both the PHP and HTML files, then the PHP one will be served, and not the HTML one. If you prefer to serve HTML files, then swap the two blocks around.

Unfortunately, I don't know of a good way to force a trailing slash for these, specifically because of the condition that checks for their existence. In other words, it won't work if you request `sub2/`, with the trailins slash because it would need to check if `sub2/.php` exists, which it does not.

**Update:** For added benefit, place these two blocks just below the new `RewriteBase` you set earlier to redirect the old URIs to the new ones whilst allowing the rewrites to the new URIs to still work:

```bash
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/project\.php\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ project/id/%1/ [R=302,L,QSD]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/MyWeb/(.+)\.(php|html)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
```

For reference, here's the complete file: http://hastebin.com/gacapesoqe.rb

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very helpful and explanatory. Is there a source that you're aware of where I can learn this from ground up?

Comment: There are plenty of resources online - perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained) can get you started.